# Cocos2d vs UIKit

Tags: iphone, uikit, cocos2d-iphone

When I try to use UIView with cocos2d I have a problem.
I create UIViewController, add view to it and add view to window:

```
helpController=[[HelpController alloc] init];
helpController.view=view;
[[[[Director sharedDirector] openGLView] window] addSubview: helpController.view];

@interface HelpController : UIViewController
{
}
@end
@implementation HelpController
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation {
 return  YES;
}
@end
```

This is function that remove view from window and run other cocos scene:

```
-(void)back:(id)sender {
 FadeTransition *tran=[FadeTransition transitionWithDuration:0.5f scene:[MainMenuScene node]];
 [helpController.view removeFromSuperview];
 [[Director sharedDirector] replaceScene:tran];

}
```

First time:
http://tinyurl.com/nu98ub

The screen orientation is UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight.
First time then I run scene with this view, this view orientation is Landscape, but next times is Portrait, I can't resolve this problem. Somebody help me, please :)

Comment: This is next time:
http://tinyurl.com/myk3yw

Answer (score 3):

This URL
http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/wiki/doku.php/tips:cocos2d_and_uikitlayer
Contains a class which addresses just your problem.
Not exactly a timely answer, but hopefully that helps